# How do I inject a specific instance of a class in some Spring tests?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I have a Spring component, which takes a Clock as a dependency:

```
@Component
public class MyClass {
    private final Clock clock;

    @Autowired
    public MyClass(Clock clock){
        this.clock = clock
    }
}
```

For most of my tests, I have a mock Clock that is annotated as a `@Bean` and is correctly injected. However, for some of my tests, I need to use a different mocked clock. How can I use a different mock for these tests?

```
public class MyClassTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Test
    public void test1(){
         // use the standard mock clock
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
         // inject clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2018-01-01T00:00:00Z"), UTC);
    }


    @Test
    public void test3(){
         // inject clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2019-12-12T23:59:59Z"), UTC);
    }
}
```

So in this example, I want to override the mocked clock in `test2` and `test3`.

Comment: Muliple options: mock different clock instances which will be resetet on `@Before setup()` or create a method for normal `clockMock` which does change the current time. If there are only private methods/fields for setting this afterwards you can use `WhiteBox` for access privates on test-purpose.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ReflectionTestUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html) to inject the various mocks.  It was made for this purpose.

```
@Test
public void test2(){
     // inject clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2018-01-01T00:00:00Z"), UTC);
     ReflectionTestUtils.setField(myClass, "clock", mockClock);
}
```

Comment: Much better solution when you cannot inject `Clock` in classes that are not part of Spring DI.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way to deal with such usecase is using Mockito lib with only one bean and just change the stub method implementation on demand:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public Clock clock(){
        return Mockito.mock(Clock.class);
    }    
}

public class MyClassTest {

    @Autowired
    private Clock clock;

    @Autowired
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Test
    public void test1(){
         // use the standard mock clock
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
         Mockito.when(clock.giveMeAValue()).thenReturn(Instant.parse("2018-01-01T00:00:00Z"), UTC);               
    }    

    @Test
    public void test3(){   
       Mockito.when(clock.giveMeAValue()).thenReturn(Instant.parse("2019-12-12T23:59:59Z"), UTC);

    }
}
```

Mockito is already provided by spring-boot-starter-test.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look to all options that you have.

### Replace dependency manually

Like it was advised in other answers you can use `ReflectionTestUtils` if the field is private or create a setter. This is a simple method but it has some downsides you should be aware of.

If `MyClass` invokes some other class `OtherClockClient` that as well uses clock that class is unaware of such replacement and you may get inconsistency because two clocks a hanging around.

The other problem is that manual replacement corrupts spring context. It is important because spring context is reused between tests by default and test order is not guaranteed. It means that it may happen that `test2` will be executed before `test1` and "standard" clock will not be used in `test1`. If `test1` relies on the behaviour of implicitly set "standard" clock you are in trouble.

To solve this you either can mark test with [`@DirtiesContext`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html) or manually revert the dependency.

### Single Dispatcher

You can always inject the same clock in tests and by default it should demonstrate the behaviour you named "standard". However it can provide additional API that allows tests to configure the clock for their need.

```
public class ConfigurableClock implements Clock {
    void fixAt(Instant instant) {
    }
}

public class MyClassTest {

  @Autowired
  private ConfigurableClock clock;

  @Test
  public void test1() {
    // use standard clock behaviour
  }

  @Test
  public void test2(){
     clock.fixAt(Instant.parse("2018-01-01T00:00:00Z"));
  }
```

In this case there is no need to rewire beans but the state should still be reset so that tests that expect implicit default clock have it. You can either  do reset of the clock in `@Before`/`@After` methods:

```
@Before
public setUp() {
   clock.reset();
}

@After
public tearDown() {
   clock.reset();
}
```

Or add a [TestExecutionListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestExecutionListener.html) that will do that.